# Composer detecting older version of PHP

Tags: magento2, php, version, ssh

I'm trying to install Magento 2 via composer and following [this link](http://magenest.com/how-to-install-magento-2-on-centos/) for instructions. In step 2,

```
composer install
```

I get a php version error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/composer 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.0.2].
    - magento/composer 1.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[v0.1.1].
    - pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for league/climate 2.6.1 -> satisfiable by league/climate[2.6.1].
    - league/climate 2.6.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for sjparkinson/static-review 4.1.1 -> satisfiable by sjparkinson/static-review[4.1.1].
    - sjparkinson/static-review 4.1.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for symfony/stopwatch v3.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/stopwatch[v3.2.1].
    - symfony/stopwatch v3.2.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.1 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.1 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.1 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.1].
```

I changed my php version in cpanel to 5.5 but using `php -v` still showed 5.3. So I followed [this link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/general-server-setup/how-do-i-change-php-version-in-shell) to add an alias to `~/.bashrc` file

```
alias php=/opt/php55/bin/php
```

Logged out and back in to SSH and `php -v` returns 5.5. Went back to install composer and it showed the exact same error. I've also did what was mentioned on [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92118/magento-2-running-on-plesk-12-5-and-older-versions-of-php) but it didn't work either.

How do I update php for composer?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 requires minimum PHP 5.5.22 and above. For more info, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Like I said, I have upgraded to 5.5, it says I have 5.3

Comment: What is the exact php version?

Comment: `php -v` returns 5.5.38

Comment: I have had this kind of problem once like old versions in terminal and composer. I have set the path $ export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin/php:$PATH where the path should navigate to the new version. In your case, v5.5. Then I restarted the server and that worked for me. Maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this so just want to clear a few things. When I enter `whereis php` I get the following url `/opt/php55/bin/php` among other things. So do I have to write `$ export PATH=/opt/php55/bin/php:$PATH`, Then execute `composer install`? Also do I have to restart the entire server or `httpd restart` would do?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try this answer - http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04